# Does Iron PDF Require the printer to be connected to a Network?

Tags: javascript, c#, pdf, printing, ironpdf

I am wondering as I have been testing Iron PDF out, do you require the printer to be on the local network ie. cat5 to POE?

The current printer on the network works but when attempting to use a USB printer (which works normally) - it does not work.

Comment: Yeah, I managed to fix the issue - printers do not need to be over ethernet. They just need the right drivers installed on the server host. Also, make sure that the setting "spooling" is disabled so it prints straight away.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the issue

Primarily, I found that printers do not need to be over ethernet, they just need a connection to the server such as USB or ethernet.
They also need the right drivers installed on the server host (usually found online).

Also, make sure that the setting "spooling" is disabled on the printer settings and preview within the ironPDF setting is false so it prints straight away.

For note:
I was using an iis www server and hosting it over a local network, using a "server" with the database on and a "client" accessing the data.

the **server** needs to have all the compatible drivers for your printer as it is **the server that does the printing**. Therefore, client printers will not work and will only be server-side (unless local hosted where the client and server is the same machine)